# Creating the object then pass the values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have Multi-level hierarchies will be on a select list. Now that I have a table, he may select values from the subsequent column and push them into the filter by clicking the column.

```js
var name = ['Akansha', Navya]

var age = ['24', '26']

var id = ['2345', '34555']
```

All of those values must now be passed in JSON format to the filter. The actual hierarchy will look as follows since we must follow to the hirearchy in order to push the values that are in the json format.

```
Values: Array(2)
```

I must build the same array list because these Values is predefined in the JSON.

```
Values:(2)
0:{name:'Akansha', age:'24', id:'2345'}
1:{name:'Navya', age:'26', id:'34555'}
```

I used a for loop to build the array list, which will produce the same array list as needed.

```js
var nameValues =[];

for(var i=0; i < name.length; i++){
 var  filterValue = new nam3({ // name3 object is prdefined for the filter so i have insitalize the object
name: name[i];
age: age[i];
id: id[i]
});
nameValues.push(filterValue);
}

console.log(nameValues); //This gives me the same array list and format the values as required.
//(2)
//0:{name:'Akansha', age:'24', id:'2345'}
//1:{name:'Navya', age:'26', id:'34555'}
```

Now i have to push name.values to the filter .Product is the filter id

`product.values.push(nameValues);`
I have therefore added these values to the Values Array's product filter. But, the problem is that when I push those data, a nested array is created, which causes an object reference error.
When I send the JSON array to the filter, It appears Like This In the Console.
This is the result I receive after running the entire script.

```
Values:Array(1)
       0: Array(2)
          0:{name:'Akansha', age:'24', id:'2345'}
          1:{name:'Navya', age:'26', id:'34555'}
T
```

But the output we required

```
Values:(2)
0:{name:'Akansha', age:'24', id:'2345'}
1:{name:'Navya', age:'26', id:'34555'}
```

Now I have the pass nameValue in the Values Array that are in Json . Can anybody help me with this

m not sure how we can accomplish this to pass it in the Values Array right now. I'm new to javascript, so figuring out how to resolve this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat or spread operator or push with spread

```js
const a = [{name:'Akansha', age:'24', id:'2345'},
{name:'Navya', age:'26', id:'34555'}]

const product = {values: [{name:'Hello', age:'25', id:'2335'}]}
product.values = product.values.concat(a)

console.log(product.values)

const product2 = {values: [{name:'Hello', age:'25', id:'2335'}]}

product2.values = [...product2.values,...a]

console.log(product2.values)

const product3 = {values: [{name:'Hello', age:'25', id:'2335'}]}

product3.values.push(...a)

console.log(product3.values)
```

Comment: The Values is predefined object in the JSOn so we only need to pass array also name age is dynamically coming up from the database that is not static

Comment: what i mean is you can use concat instead of push to connect to the array

Comment: What diffrence it makes ?